# What did I forget in order to correctly send an email using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail, scrapy

I wanna use Scrapy to send an email

I read throw the official website, and I found that I can do this:

```
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
        from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
        settings = get_project_settings()
        mailer = MailSender(mailfrom ="Something@gmail.com", smtphost="smtp.gmail.com", smtpport=465, smtppass ="MySecretPassword")
        mailer.send(to=["AnotherMail@gmail.com"], subject="Some subject", body="Some body")
```

The code didn't throw any exception, but there is no mail has been sent.

What did I miss?

#### Note1:

I need to work with Scrapy framework, and not pure Python

#### Note2:

I don't wanna apply the default settings by using `mailer = MailSender.from_settings(settings)`, because as you saw, i have my custom options, and bty i tried to use the default settings, but the same result, no exception, but no emails sent.

I hope you help me

Comment: Try passing `smtptls=True` to MailSender. Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411033/sending-e-mail-after-scrape-in-scrapy

Comment: Note that the code in that answer uses port `587` -- I haven't tried it, tho.

Comment: @elias I tried adding the `smtptls`, and still nothing is being sent, plus, i don't want to copy that ansewr because it is not 100% scrapy framework. i would like to know my mistake in this code

Comment: Do you have running anti-virus software?  I had a similar email-sending frustration until I had added an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Two things come to mind with your code. First, whether the mailer code being executed and, second, the `smtpuser` parameter should be populated.

Here is working code to send email via Gmail using Scrapy. This answer has 4 sections: email code, complete example, logging, and Gmail configuration. The complete example is provided as there are a few things that need to be coordinated for this to work.

**Email Code**

To have Scrapy send email, you can add the following in your Spider class (complete example in next section). These examples have Scrapy send email after crawling has completed.

There are two chunks of code to add, the first to import modules and the second to send the email.

Importing modules:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
```

Inside your Spider class definition:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    <SPIDER CODE>

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        mailer = MailSender(mailfrom="Something@gmail.com",smtphost="smtp.gmail.com",smtpport=587,smtpuser="Something@gmail.com",smtppass="MySecretPassword")
        return mailer.send(to=["AnotherMail@gmail.com"],subject="Some subject",body="Some body")
```

**Complete Example**

Putting this together, this example uses the dirbot example located at:

https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot

Only one file needs to be edited:

```
./dirbot/spiders/dmoz.py
```

Here is the entire working file with the imports near the top and the email code at the end of the spider class:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import Website

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.mail import MailSender

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        The lines below is a spider contract. For more info see:
        http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html

        @url http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/
        @scrapes name
        """
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
            items.append(item)

        return items

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        mailer = MailSender(mailfrom="Something@gmail.com",smtphost="smtp.gmail.com",smtpport=587,smtpuser="Something@gmail.com",smtppass="MySecretPassword")
        return mailer.send(to=["AnotherMail@gmail.com"],subject="Some subject",body="Some body")
```

Once this file is updated, run the standard crawl command from the project directory to crawl and send the email:

```
$ scrapy crawl dmoz
```

**Logging**

By returning the output of the `mailer.send` method in the `spider_closed` method, Scrapy will automatically add the result to its log. Here are examples of successes and failures:

Success Log Message:

```
2015-03-22 23:24:30-0000 [scrapy] INFO: Mail sent OK: To=['AnotherMail@gmail.com'] Cc=None Subject="Some subject" Attachs=0
```

Error Log Message - Unable to Connect:

```
2015-03-22 23:39:45-0000 [scrapy] ERROR: Unable to send mail: To=['AnotherMail@gmail.com'] Cc=None Subject="Some subject" Attachs=0- Unable to connect to server.
```

Error Log Message - Authentication Failure:

```
2015-03-22 23:38:29-0000 [scrapy] ERROR: Unable to send mail: To=['AnotherMail@gmail.com'] Cc=None Subject="Some subject" Attachs=0- 535 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 sb4sm6116233pbb.5 - gsmtp
```

**Gmail Configuration**

To configure Gmail to accept email this way, you need to enable "Access for less secure apps" which you can do at the URL below when you are logged in to the account:

```
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using a gmail address as referenced by your code? If so, google typically blocks access to outgoing mail for the first time when you do this. I run into this problem all the time when using PHPMailer. Try running your script first, then visit this link: https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha which will give you a continue button from google. Click that continue button which will verify it's you trying to send out the mail. Then try running your script again and see if that works.

Comment: I just did what you said, and I still don't get any exception, but don't receive any email

Comment: Have you also tried using port 587 instead of 465? Also some web hosts block those ports so you can't send mail through them. I know GoDaddy specifically blocks outgoing mail so if you're on a godaddy hosting plan, you won't be able to send mail like this. If the port / tls=true options do not work try contacting your host and see if they allow you to send mail through those ports. Also, I've had awesome luck using a third party mailing company SendGrid which allows for better email deliverability, and you don't have to worry about ports and other hosting nonsense. sendgrid.com

Comment: Yes I tried already the `587` port, and still the same result. Actually I can't use the third party sending male, it is against the company's policy

Comment: Understood, unfortunately I don't know much about scrappy but if it's not throwing errors it will be hard to debug. Maybe while you wait for more answers, contact your host and make sure they allow you to send mail through those ports. As I mentioned, godaddy does not allow you to, so it would not surprise me if that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy mail doesn't work for me. I use this instead:

```
def send_mail(self, message, title):
    print "Sending mail..........."
    import smtplib
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
    gmailUser = 'mail_you_send_from@gmail.com'
    gmailPassword = 'password'
    recipient = 'mail_to_send_to'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = gmailUser
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = title
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, recipient, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
    print "Mail sent"
```