# Error when trying to send email via scrapy spider: Connection was refused by other side: 10061

Tags: scrapy

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, I'm getting the following error:

> [scrapy.mail] ERROR: Unable to send mail: To=['reg2@mydomain.com']
>   Cc=['reg3@mydomain.com'] Subject="test" Attachs=0- Connection was refused
>   by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it..

Here is my very basic spider

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.mail import MailSender
mailer = MailSender()


class FanaticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fanatics'

    start_urls = ['https://www.fanaticsoutlet.com/nfl/new-england-patriots/new-england-patriots-majestic-showtime-logo-cool-base-t-shirt-navy/o-9172+t-70152507+p-1483408147+z-8-1114341320',
                 ]

    def parse(self, response):

        yield {

            'sale-price': response.xpath('//span[@data-talos="pdpProductPrice"]/span[@class="sale-price"]/text()').re('[$]\d+\.\d+'),

             }

mailer.send(to=["reg2@mydomain.com"], subject="test", body="test", cc=["reg3@mydomain.com"])
```

In my settings.py I have the following:

```
MAIL_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.com'
MAIL_FROM = 'pricealerts@mydomain.com'
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USER = 'pricealerts@mydomain.com'
MAIL_PASS = 'passwordxx'
MAIL_SSL = True
```

It seems like these server details aren't getting pulled properly? I've tried modifying all the options I could, including trying to populate the settings in the spider but that gave me another problem. 
`mailer=MailSender(smtpuser="pricealerts@mydomain.com", mailfrom="pricealerts@mydomain.com", smtphost="mail.mydomain.com", smtppass="password", smtpport=465)`
This didn't give me any errors but the spider seems to hang after [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished) and I have to close the anaconda command prompt. Also, no email gets sent.

I also tried this alternate method found here and didn't get an error but no email was sent [What did I forget in order to correctly send an email using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146448/what-did-i-forget-in-order-to-correctly-send-an-email-using-scrapy)

Comment: I used the regular python code found here https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email/ and was able to get it working quite easily. I still don't know what was wrong with the scrapy specific version. Hopefully the generic version won't be an issue later in the project!

Comment: I am getting the same issue and cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have that same error try to use some proxies its works for me