# E-Mailing with Scrapy Basics

Tags: python, email, scrapy, extract

I have the following code, and I need the exported items to be emailed to me so I can see the news. I am aware of [Scrapy - 1.4 - Email Docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html?_ga=2.103430464.1317838679.1497877548-259080574.1497877548#mail-settings) and I just can't seem to find enough examples to be able to do the same with my code.

What's a good way to start this code? If not can I get pointed to some examples?

```
import scrapy
import collections

from collections import OrderedDict
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from tickers.items import tickersItem
class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "EmperyScraper"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=UNXL,UQM,URRE,UUUU,VBLT,VGZ,VKTX,VTGN,WINT,XGTI,XTNT,XXII,ZSAN',)
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        item = collections.OrderedDict()
        item['Title'] = node.xpath(
            'title/text()').extract_first()
        item['PublishDate'] = node.xpath(
            'pubDate/text()').extract_first()
        item['Description'] = node.xpath(
            'description/text()').extract_first()      
        item['Link'] = node.xpath(
            'link/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

**Update:** I am also looking into methods to make it automated!

Edit: 
Below is my code in the pipelines.py file. When I run this script I get an out put of `>>>y` and that's it. Really confusing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

class TickersPipeline(object):
    def send_mail(self, message, title):
        from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
        gmailUser = 'example@gmail.com'
        gmailPassword = 'example'
        recipient = 'example@gmail.com'

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = gmailUser
        msg['To'] = recipient
        msg['Subject'] = title
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.starttls()
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)
        mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, recipient, msg.as_string())
        mailServer.close()
```

Comment: Is there something you need to know beyond what is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411162/131187?

Comment: It doesn't work. For some reason when I use that similar code I am able to scrape, but I do not get any e-mails.

Comment: I was referring to the code that starts with `from scrapy.mail import MailSender`. OK, start small. I assume that `parse_node` `yield`s useful email items. Try putting in the last two of the three lines of code just before the `yield` with your own email address (in a list) in the 'To' and 'cc' fields and the rest the same. See what happens. If it works. Try shoving stuff from `item` into `body` and see how far you get.

Comment: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2375 
I tried it and ran into the issue. I looked up the issue and found the link above^^
This is the root of the issue I bet. It turns out you can't run this email function on Python 3+. I'll have to call pythons pre-installed smtp function. Where exactly can I loop this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide, cobbled together from one of the basic tutorials offered for scrapy.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import smtplib


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        server = smtplib.SMTP(my_server, port=587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(my_user, my_pswd)
        server.sendmail(my_email, [my_email], filename)
        server.quit()

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()
```